What questions should be tagged [hsk]?
There's a tag hsk which refers to the HSK exam.

HSK or 汉语水平考试 (Hànyǔ Shuǐpíng Kǎoshì) is a standardised Chinese proficiency test for non-native speakers of Chinese. The test is administered by the Chinese National Office for Teaching Chinese as a Foreign Language (NOTCFL, also known as Hàn Bàn / 汉办), an agency affiliated with the Ministry of Education of the People's Republic of China.

The excerpt doesn't say what questions should have this tag.
Question: What questions should be tagged [hsk]?
It's not obvious to me, it could cover:

questions about the HSK itself;
questions relating to problems on the HSK (e.g. past exams);
questions relating to HSK textbooks (which?).


Checking out the other language sites and their standardized exams:

English Language and Usage [ielts]
English Language Learners [ielts]
Esperanto [ker-exams]
French (??)
German [proficiency-test]
Italian (??)
Japanese [jlpt].  When to use the JLPT tag?
Korean [topik].
Latin (??)
Portuguese (??)
Russian (??)
Spanish (??)
Ukrainian (??)

